# wsdl return an array of complex types

Tags: wsdl, xsd

I have defined a web service that will return the data from my mysql data base.

I have written the web service in php.

Now I have defined a complex type as follows:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Category',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
    'category_parent_id' => array('name' => 'category_parent_id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'category_child_id' => array('name' => 'category_child_id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'category_list' => array('name' => 'category_list', 'type' => 'xsd:int')
)
```

);

The above complex type is a row in a table in my database.

Now my function must send an array of these rows so how do I achieve the same

My code is as follows:

```
require_once('./nusoap/nusoap.php');
$server = new soap_server;

$server->configureWSDL('productwsdl', 'urn:productwsdl');

// Register the data structures used by the service
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Category',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'category_parent_id' => array('name' => 'category_parent_id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
        'category_child_id' => array('name' => 'category_child_id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
        'category_list' => array('name' => 'category_list', 'type' => 'xsd:int')
    )
);
$server->register('getaproduct',                    // method name
    array(),          // input parameters
    //array('return' => array('result' => 'tns:Category')),    // output parameters
    array('return' =>  'tns:Category'),    // output parameters
    'urn:productwsdl',                         // namespace
    'urn:productwsdl#getaproduct',                   // soapaction
    'rpc',                                    // style
    'encoded',                                // use
    'Get the product categories'        // documentation
);

function getaproduct()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('sssl', $conn);
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM jos_vm_category_xref";
     $q = mysql_query($sql);
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
     {
         $items[] = array('category_parent_id'=>$r['category_parent_id'],
                              'category_child_id'=>$r['category_child_id'],
                              'category_list'=>$r['category_list']);
     }
       return $items;
}


    // Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Comment: Yeah I know the formatting ain't right but guys I pasted the code in the code block provided by the editor but it doesn't seem to work.
If some can tell me why or someone can edit it for me it will be great

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured the answer myself after searching the internet.

Following is the code to create a complex data type. Here I am creating a datatype Person whch has firstname, age and gender as its data members.

```php
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
  'Person',
  'complexType',
  'struct',
  'all',
  '',
  array(
    'firstname' => array('name' => 'firstname', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'age'       => array('name' => 'age', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'gender'    => array('name' => 'gender', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
  )
);
```

Next we must create another new datatype which is an array of the datatype we have created. I call it the person array and the code for it is below:

```php
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'PersonArray',    // Name
    'complexType',    // Type Class
    'array',          // PHP Type
    '',               // Compositor
    'SOAP-ENC:Array', // Restricted Base
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Person[]')
    ),
    'tns:Person'
);
```

Now I registered a function called getPeople which takes no input parameters but return an array of persons as:

```php
$server->register(
    'getPeople',                          // method name
    array(),                              // input parameters
    array('return' => 'tns:PersonArray'), // output parameters
    'urn:hellowsdl2',                     // namespace
    'urn:hellowsdl2#getPeople',           // soapaction
    'rpc',                                // style
    'encoded',                            // use
    'Return an array of people'           // documentation
);
```

and programmed the function to return some dummy data as:

```php
function getPeople()
{
    $peopleArray = array();
    $peopleArray[] = array(
        'firstname' => "Anand",
        'age'       => 25,
        'gender'    => "Male"
    );

    $peopleArray[] = array(
        'firstname' => "Sandhya",
        'age'       => 21,
        'gender'    => "Female"
    );

    return $peopleArray;
}
```

by the way I am sorry I haven't mentioned but all this code is in PHP.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Great, my friend, your example helped my a lot to solve my problem in webservice creation in nusoap :-) Thank you very much !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me solving an issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. I believe nusoap is not used so much nowadays by PHP developers. However I required it for my work, and your post was useful for me.